# React event handler not removing object from array of objects (useState)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, onclick, react-props

I am trying to make a playlist app where you can use the search results to create your own playlist. Ive successfully been able to pass the songs from my search results to the playlist but when I try to remove them I can't remove the whole card. Instead only the artist, song and album disappear but the card stays in the list.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr4fq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUiED.png)

as you can see after I click the remove button the card remains but its text disappears.

this is what my files look like

top level app component

```
import { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";
import SearchResults from "./SearchResults";
import Playlist from "./Playlist";
import styles from "../Styles/App.module.css";

const generateKey = () => {
  let num = "";
  let characters =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  const chars = characters.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    num += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chars));
  }

  return num;
};

function App() {
  const [playlistTracks, setPlaylistTracks] = useState([]);
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([
    {
      song: "Go Baby",
      artist: "Lupe",
      album: "Food and Liqour",
      id: generateKey(),
    },
    {
      song: "Demon Days",
      artist: "Gorillaz",
      album: "Self titled",
      id: generateKey(),
    },
  ]);

  const onAdd = (track) => {
    setPlaylistTracks((prevTracks) => [...prevTracks, track]);
  };

  const onRemove = (e) => {
    console.log(playlistTracks);
    setPlaylistTracks([playlistTracks.filter((song) => song.id == e.id)]);
  };

  return (
    <div id={styles.app}>
      <header>
        <h1>Spotify Playlist App</h1>
      </header>
      <SearchBar />
      <main>
        <SearchResults searchResults={searchResults} onAdd={onAdd} />
        <Playlist
          playlistTracks={playlistTracks}
          name="playlist"
          onRemove={onRemove}
        />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

this is my playlist component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styles from "../Styles/Playlist.module.css";
import Tracklist from "./Tracklist";

function Playlist(props) {
  const { playlistTracks } = props;
  const [name, setName] = useState("Playlist");

  const nameList = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setName(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div id={styles.playlist}>
      <h3>{name}</h3>
      <input onChange={nameList} type="text" />
      <Tracklist
        tracks={playlistTracks}
        string="playlist"
        onRemove={props.onRemove}
      />
      <button>Save to Spotify</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Playlist;
```

tracklist component

```
import React from "react";
import Track from "./Track";

function Tracklist(props) {
  const generateKey = () => {
    let num = "";
    let characters =
      "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    const chars = characters.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      num += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chars));
    }

    return num;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {props.tracks.map((track) => {
        return (
          <Track
            key={generateKey()}
            track={track}
            onAdd={props.onAdd}
            onRemove={props.onRemove}
            string={props.string}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Tracklist;
```

track component

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import styles from "../Styles/Track.module.css";

function Track(props) {
  const string = props.string;

  const choice = () => {
    switch (string) {
      case "search": {
        return <button onClick={() => props.onAdd(props.track)}>+</button>;
      }
      case "playlist": {
        return <button onClick={() => props.onRemove(props.track)}>-</button>;
      }
      default: {
        return undefined;
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div id={styles.track}>
      <div id={styles.track_info}>
        <h4>{props.track.song}</h4>
        <p>
          {props.track.artist} | {props.track.album}
        </p>
      </div>
      {choice()}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Track;
```

I tried to remove the card that was added from the search results but to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your `onRemove()` function may be incorrectly coded.

```js
setPlaylistTracks([playlistTracks.filter((song) => song.id == e.id)]);
```

This would create an array of arrays every time it is called. The result of `playlistTracks.filter()` would be an array, and then you pass create a single-member array which has the result of `playlistTracks.filter()`, thus an array of arrays. Instead, consider removing the outer array constructor:

```js
setPlaylistTracks(playlistTracks.filter((song) => song.id == e.id));
```

Furthermore, since the function is named `onRemove`, it seems like you may be after *removing* the passed track from the state. Currently, this will exclude all other tracks apart from the passed track. Consider reversing the logic in the `filter()` callback to be (strictly) not equal to (`!==`):

```js
setPlaylistTracks(playlistTracks.filter((song) => song.id !== e.id));
```

Lastly, to prevent any possible stale state, consider passing a function to `setPlaylistTracks`. This function will receive the latest state and return the new state:

```js
setPlaylistTracks((tracks) => tracks.filter((song) => song.id !== e.id));
```

```js
const { useState, useCallback } = React;

function Playlist(props) {
  const { playlistTracks } = props;
  const [name, setName] = useState("Playlist");

  const nameList = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setName(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div id={styles.playlist}>
      <h3>{name}</h3>
      <input onChange={nameList} type="text" />
      <Tracklist
        tracks={playlistTracks}
        string="playlist"
        onRemove={props.onRemove}
      />
      <button>Save to Spotify</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Tracklist(props) {
  const generateKey = () => {
    let num = "";
    let characters =
      "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    const chars = characters.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      num += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chars));
    }

    return num;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {props.tracks.map((track) => {
        return (
          <Track
            key={generateKey()}
            track={track}
            onAdd={props.onAdd}
            onRemove={props.onRemove}
            string={props.string}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const styles = {
  track: 'track',
  track_info: 'track_info',
};

function Track(props) {
  const string = props.string;

  const choice = () => {
    switch (string) {
      case "search": {
        return <button onClick={() => props.onAdd(props.track)}>+</button>;
      }
      case "playlist": {
        return <button onClick={() => props.onRemove(props.track)}>-</button>;
      }
      default: {
        return undefined;
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div id={styles.track}>
      <div id={styles.track_info}>
        <h4>{props.track.song}</h4>
        <p>
          {props.track.artist} | {props.track.album}
        </p>
      </div>
      {choice()}
    </div>
  );
}

const generateKey = () => {
  let num = "";
  let characters =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  const chars = characters.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    num += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chars));
  }

  return num;
};

const SearchBar = () => 'SearchBar';
const SearchResults = ({ searchResults, onAdd }) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    {searchResults.map(result => (
      <button onClick={() => onAdd(result)}>
        {result.song}
      </button>
    ))}
  </React.Fragment>
);

function App() {
  const [playlistTracks, setPlaylistTracks] = useState([]);
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([
    {
      song: "Go Baby",
      artist: "Lupe",
      album: "Food and Liqour",
      id: generateKey(),
    },
    {
      song: "Demon Days",
      artist: "Gorillaz",
      album: "Self titled",
      id: generateKey(),
    },
  ]);

  const onAdd = (track) => {
    setPlaylistTracks((prevTracks) => [...prevTracks, track]);
  };

  const onRemove = (e) => {
    console.log(playlistTracks);
    setPlaylistTracks(tracks => tracks.filter((song) => song.id !== e.id));
  };

  return (
    <div id={styles.app}>
      <header>
        <h1>Spotify Playlist App</h1>
      </header>
      <SearchBar />
      <main>
        <SearchResults searchResults={searchResults} onAdd={onAdd} />
        <Playlist
          playlistTracks={playlistTracks}
          name="playlist"
          onRemove={onRemove}
        />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```